# Some weird thing with clear both via css pseudo :after

Tags: html, css, css-float, pseudo-element

Examine this code:

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="one">Sometext over here</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="two">
```

**CSS**

```
.one {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 450px;
height: 60px;
padding-top: 25px;
color: #ffffff;
font-size:34px;
font-weight: 800;
}
.one:after { clear: both; }
.two {
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 150%;
width: 200px;
height: 20px;
  }
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dhv5t61/)

Why is the `clear both` with the `after` element not working in this example above? while the clearing with `<div style="clear:both"></div>` inside the layout it self do work.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: try this .one:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

Comment: tried it... nothing works with the pseudo element. I can't get it...

Comment: LoL. people down vote it, but not providing any solution... amazing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:after` clear float trick works on floated element *inside* the pseudo elements parent.

If you would put the `<div style="clear:both"></div>` inside the `h1` it will not clear the float either, so it has to be a sibling or a parent element of the floated element

So in your case just clear the float on the `input`

```css
.one {
  float: left;
  width: 450px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size:34px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.two {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="one">Sometext over here</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="two">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add `display: block` to input:

**CSS**

```
.one {
  display: block;
  width: 450px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: left;
}

.two {
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="one">Sometext over here</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="two">
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/2dhv5t61/5/)**

Comment: Something odd... I tried it with all of my browsers... IE, ff, chrome, opera... it's not centered for me. what the hell...

Comment: And the url that i give you...can you see if is ok? - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/2dhv5t61/2/

Comment: tried the display block before. here's what I get: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QwvFp.png

Comment: I update my answer without using floats - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/2dhv5t61/5/

Comment: I know, Luis :) I can make it work without float, I just can't understand this behavior of not clearing the float with after pseudo element while with normal div it's working

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you provide `clearfix` to parent element try this snippet hope this could help you. I'm also including `:before` but this is the best way to clear the floats. here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/rhulkashyap/jjv6t6gd/

```css
.one {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 450px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  color: #111;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.two {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <h1 class="one">Sometext over here</h1>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="two">
```

Comment: I can simply use the `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the `h1` tag... i'm not looking for an extra layout